# R to Python translation

Tags: python, r

I am trying to convert some code from r to python but am struggling to find a way to do it as I am new to python. I am trying to reduce levels of gender column to 3 categories but I cant find a quick concise way to do this in Python. Any help is appreciated.

```
levels(data$Sex)<- c(levels(data$Sex),"Other")  
levels(data$Sex)[levels(data$Sex) %in% c("" , " " , "0", "C")]<-"Other"  
levels(data$Sex)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, may be you are looking for something like, you have this:

```
    Text
0       
1       
2      0
3      C
4  Hello
5  World
```

Python equivalent code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Text'] = [' ', '', '0', 'C', 'Hello', 'World']
textList = [' ', '', '0', 'C']
df['Text'] = np.where(df['Text'].isin(textList), 'Other', df['Text'])
```

Output you get:

```
df
Out[7]: 
    Text
0  Other
1  Other
2  Other
3  Other
4  Hello
5  World
```

You now came down from 6 levels to 3 levels in your Text category by looking for particular strings and replacing them with `Other`.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for!